# Why did Jabba's ships have to hover?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, jabba-the-hutt

Jabba's hovering sail barges just seem so stupid.  Is there any reasonable motivation Jabba might have had for using hovering ships when he could just use sandcrawlers or something, which I assume are less expensive and require less energy and credits to maintain?

Comment: And probably slower.

Comment: "Just seem so stupid"... a bad way to start a question in a site for science fiction and fantasy works :) Also, I take it you're not familiar with [The Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool)?

Comment: @AndresF. My name and "Cool" have never been used in a sentence together.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Three reasons come to mind:

### For effect.

Imagine you are this warlord on Tatooine.  You carry a lot of wealth and want to appear as being so.  What better way than to float above that dirty, hot sand in a sail barge?  It must be expensive to run, which shows just how important its owner must be!

### Comfort.

Related to the first reason, but if you are wealthy and have lots of parties, going up and over sand dunes on crazy angles is going to spill the drinks.  The sail barge can hold itself level and keep everyone comfortable.

### *Lots* of people use hovercraft on Tatooine!

Think of Luke's landspeeder in Episode IV.  It's much the same thing, but sits lower to the ground and is a lot smaller.

### Travel time (thanks @WadCheber!)

Sandcrawlers are these huge, lumbering things that travel at roughly the same speed as a sick bantha.  Wouldn't it be better to nip over to the Sarlaac pit, drop in the prisoners and be back to the lair in time for the after party?

Put all of those together and it's a compelling argument over a sand crawler :)

Comment: Excellent answer.  I'd add convenience/practicality - sand crawlers move at a glacial pace.  It would take weeks to get from his palace to the Sarlacc Pit.  A sail barge would get you there in minutes/hours.

Comment: @WadCheber Thanks!  Good point on travelling time!  Mind if I add it to the answer?

Comment: Go ahead. And you have my +1.

Comment: Sand gets in your wheel bearings

Comment: @Richard I've had some mornings like that...

Comment: @JaneS - I don't like sand. It's coarse and rough and irritating and it gets everywhere.

Comment: @Richard NOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!

Comment: (Speculating, so a comment, but) I'd prefer to float (high enough) over a Sarlacc pit instead of rolling up to its edge.

Comment: @WadCheber It would take so long to deliver prisoners to the Sarlacc Pit using sand crawlers, I wouldn't even bother.

Answer (score 3):

According to the new Star Wars junior novelisation '[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)' Jabba's motivation to get a Sail Barge was a mixture of comfort, convenience and the desire for a display of ostentatious wealth that befitted his reputation as a key mover-and-shaker in the Sector.

> *JABBA, OF COURSE, has never been satisfied with the various
>   landspeeders and skyhoppers that the common folk of Tatooine use to
>   get across the treacherous deserts.*
>
> *To travel in luxury and style, he purchased a massive sail barge — an
>   energy-guzzling monstrosity that carries him and his entourage five or
>   six meters above the hot sand on a cushion of antigravity.*
>
> *Today the barge is a floating party. The crowd from the throne
>   room — even Max Rebo and the band—lounges about in the barge’s dark,
>   fetid hold. Zooming over the Dune Sea toward the Pit of Carkoon, they
>   indulge in the many pleasures their gleeful host has provided. Jabba
>   is not always so generous, so they are making the most of his good
>   mood.*

The (admittedly Legends-canon) [Star Wars: Essential Guide to Vehicles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Vehicles_and_Vessels) also mentions two other motives; **Speed and tradition**

> Like many luxury craft, no two sail barges are exactly alike. Most
>   utilize three-chambered repulsor-lift engines to cruise over a
>   planet's surface at about 100 kilometers per hour.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question. It compares the barge to other hovercraft-type vehicles while the question is to explicitly find out why he didn't choose something that doesn't float above the sand.